What is the difference between a meddler and a busybody?
There seem to be a lot of overlaps.
The criminal angrily raved: If it hadn't been for that busybody/meddler who overheard my conversation with the others and tipped off the police about the plan, everything would have worked out.
Some countries consider the US a busybody/meddler that arbitrarily interferes in other countries' affairs whenever it sees that as beneficial.

A "meddler" is someone who interferes in other people's affairs. A "busybody" is someone who gossips about other people's affairs. If I told everyone that you had an argument with your girlfriend, I would be a busybody. If I called your girlfriend and told her that she was wrong and should apologize, I would be a meddler.
That said, "busybuddy" is also sometimes used for someone who interferes in other people's affairs. But mostly, it just means a gossip.

A busybody is also someone who wants to know things about another person, even if they don't gossip about it.

@WeatherVane True. I was going to say something about that and forgot to mention it.

IOW they are nosy.

A meddler meddles; they do things which have an effect on people. A busybody might listen in, might offer unsolicited advice, or might interfere actively. Another difference is that a busybody typically has no legitimate interest, e.g. a neighbour or acquaintance: a meddler might refer to a mother who intervenes excessively in her child's life, a boss who interferes with staff, etc.
